# Python: Iterate through text file; return a different line than referenced in 'if' statement

Tags: python, iterator, xlsx, attributeerror, text-extraction

I'm attempting to iterate through a *.txt file and return lines (strings) that meet certain conditions--which will be written to an *.xlsx.

The code is working for the `if "API" and "77-003" in line:` condition, which returns the line in which **"API" and "77-003"** occur.
However, the block shown below is still returning the line that **includes "API", but not "67025"**. I want it to return the **next** line in the *.txt file. Here, I tried `line = line.next()` so that the **next** line would be returned.

```
elif "API" in line and "67025" not in line:
     line = line.next()
     api = line.rstrip('"\n').lstrip('API,"')
     worksheet.write(count, 0, api)
     worksheet.write(count, 1, count)
```

But I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-a94ba137ca11> in <module>
     55             worksheet.write(count, 1, count)
     56         elif "API" in line and "42-003" not in line:
---> 57             line = line.next()
     58             api = line.rstrip('"\n').lstrip('API,"')
     59             worksheet.write(count, 0, api)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'next'
```

I've tried multiple versions of this, but can't find an option that returns the **next** line successfully, instead of returning the line that has **"API"**.

How would I return different line numbers than the one in the **if** statement?
Any help is appreciated.

Example text file:

```
API 77-003-200
well dixie #1
API
67025650
well doodle #2
API 77-003-908
well dw washburn #1
```

What I want:

```
77-003-200   | 1
67025650     | 4
77-003-908   | 6
```

What I'm getting:

```
77-003-200   | 1
API          | 3
77-003-908   | 6
```

Abbreviated code below:

```
import xlsxwriter as xl
import os
from os import listdir

api = 0
row = 1

worksheet = xl.Workbook(myfile.xlsx').add_worksheet()
worksheet.write(0, 0, 'API')
worksheet.write(0, 1, 'Line Number')

count = 0

with open('C:/Project/file.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8") as text:
    for line in text:
        count += 1
        if "API" and "77-003" in line:
            api = line.rstrip('"\n').lstrip('API,"')
            worksheet.write(count, 0, api)
            worksheet.write(count, 1, count)
        elif "API" in line and "67025" not in line:
            line = line.next()
            api = line.rstrip('"\n').lstrip('API,"')
            worksheet.write(count + 1, 0, api)
            worksheet.write(count + 1, 1, count + 1)
        else:
            continue
workbook.close()
```

Comment: Try `text.next()` instead of `line.next()`.  Even if it works though you still might get a problem at the last line of the file.  A better approach would be to use a flag to indicate how you want to treat the next line in the main loop.

Comment: @MarkRansom When I use ```text.next()``` I get the following error: ```---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-380b3df552d4> in <module>
     55             worksheet.write(count, 1, count)
     56         elif "API" in line and "42-003" not in line:
---> 57             line = text.next()
     58             api = line.rstrip('"\n').lstrip('API,"')
     59             worksheet.write(count, 0, api)

AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'next'

```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of what I suggested in the comments, to use a flag to cause different processing of the next line of the file.

```
import xlsxwriter as xl
import os
from os import listdir

api = 0
row = 1

worksheet = xl.Workbook(myfile.xlsx').add_worksheet()
worksheet.write(0, 0, 'API')
worksheet.write(0, 1, 'Line Number')

count = 0

with open('C:/Project/file.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8") as text:
    flagged = False
    for line in text:
        count += 1
        if flagged:
            flagged = False
            api = line.rstrip('"\n').lstrip('API,"')
            worksheet.write(count + 1, 0, api)
            worksheet.write(count + 1, 1, count + 1)
        elif "API" in line and "77-003" in line:  # fixed an error here
            api = line.rstrip('"\n').lstrip('API,"')
            worksheet.write(count, 0, api)
            worksheet.write(count, 1, count)
        elif "API" in line and "67025" not in line:
            flagged = True
workbook.close()
```